# Net force equation on incline, tension at angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

Here's the situation: a block is on an incline. A string is attached at a certain angle and applies tension to the block in the direction up the incline. What would the net force equation look like?

My instinct is that $F_\textrm{net} = T_y + T_x - Ff - F_{gx}$ (since $F_n$ and $F_{gy}$ balance out). But, the only force in the $y$ direction is $T_y,$ which seems to indicate the box will be lifted off the incline! Is there another force acting opposite of $T_y$? In real life, even if you pull something at an angle it doesn't necessarily lift off the ground. I feel like there's some part/explanation I'm missing out on.

Would the actual net equation be $F_\textrm{net} = T_x - F_f - F_{gx}$?

Comment: Fn and Fgy do not balance out.  Please format equations using MathJax.  [Here’s a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143293).  Your notation is not at all clear.  It appears that you are adding $x$ components to $y$ components.   Either 1.) your notation is obscuring your intention (use MathJax) or 2.) you don't understand vectors and Newton's second law.

Comment: In your $F_{net}$ equations I believe that you wrote $F_{gy}$ but actually meant $F_{gx}$, am I right?

Comment: Thanks for the MathJax.  Now it's clear that you have three problems.  One  you have almost corrected:  $F_f$ and $F_{gy}$ do not cancel.   Second,  your notation is still ambiguous.  It's not clear which objects are vectors and which are components.  This leads to the third:  you can't add the $x$ and $y$ *components* as you seem to be doing in your first equation.  If the first equation was intended to be a *vector* equation, then you have left out the $x$ part of gravity.   Either way, the first equation is not right.  If you want to express the $x$ component of the net force:  $F_{net,x}$

Comment: @garyp, I believe there is simply a typo and that the OP is not in doubt about the vector addition - see my comment above.

Comment: @Steeven What about $T_x + T_y$?   Are those *component vectors* or *vector components*?   Either way, it doesn't make sense, even with your potential correction.

Comment: @garyp, well it does pretty much make sense it they are component vectors ☺️ But let's rather wait for the OP's answer.

Comment: @Steeven If component vectors, shouldn't it include $F_{gx}$?  You are right:  we need the OP to clarify things.

Comment: @garyp, exactly that would be the typo

Comment: Yes, $F_{gy}$ was a typo that has now been fixed. Sorry! The dashed lines are the x and y components of T and force of gravity. Not sure what the difference between component vectors and vector components are, but I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No rule says that $F_n$ and $F_{gy}$ must balance out.

They just often do in simple examples. But *never* remember this as a rule! Because it isn't.

The normal force $F_n$ is a "holding up"-force. It can adjust. It is only as large as it needs to be.

- Put a book on a table, and a normal force appears to hold it up.
- Add another book, and the normal force grows to the double.

In your case:

- Place a block on the incline, and the normal force appears to hold back the force that pushes against the surface. This is the y component of gravity. It balances it out completely.
- Now pull a bit outwards in the box with a string. This pull balances a bit of the gravity, so there is now less left for the normal force to withstand. The normal force is thus smaller than without the extra pull.

The total sum of these three forces is at all times zero. And that's the only rule.

---

(Except, of course, if the pull in the string is large enough to overcome gravity - then the object will fly off, and the normal force is zero and not needed since there is nothing to hold back against.)

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a lot of sense. So as tension in the string increases, normal force will decrease while force of gravity stays the same? How would you calculate that mathematically? $F_N=mgcos\theta$ would no longer apply, right?

Comment: @omnibus $F_N=mg\cos(\theta)$ never really "applies". It is just sometimes the end result in some situations. To do these kinds of problems *always* start with Newton's 1st law from scratch, as you have done in the question, and don't leave any forces out even if you think they balance out.

Comment: If I had to find for example $F_N$ then I would look in the y-direction direction alone and sun up all forces there: $$\sum F=0\\F_N+T_y-F_{gy}=0\\F_N=mg\cos(\theta) - T_y$$ and then I had to find $T_y$ as well, before this can be finished. This can be found by doing the same thing in the x direction.

Comment: When summing vectors, do you always separate the x direction and y direction as a rule? (It actually makes a lot more sense, but I was taught to sum them all together).

Comment: @omnibus. The 1st law is usually written $\sum \vec F=0$ to emphasize that it is a vector sum. So you are totally right, just sum *all* forces nomatter directions. But consider what that means mathematically: if you add vectors together, you actually add all their x coordinates together, all their y coordinates together (and all their z coordinates together in 3D). In the 1st law, each of these three coordinate sums must be 0, in order for it all be be $\sum \vec F=0$. So you can also just as well sum all the x coordinates first - which means, summing all x contributions from all forces - etc.

Comment: ... And this is also usually the easier method, since you then don't have to sum vectors but just numbers. So yes, I would always split the calculation into the x, y and z directions and from that make three separate equations.

Answer (score 1):

Force is a vector quantity so you need to use vector addition.

The net force in the x-direction is $T_{\rm x }-F_{\rm f }-F_{\rm gx }$ and the net force in the y-direction it is $F_{\rm N }+T_{\rm y }-F_{\rm gy }$ which is presumably zero.

Comment: As far as I can tell the issue here is not vector addition (even though the OP made a typo, as commented above) but the nature of the normal force.

Comment: The reason I wrote that is the writer seemed to have added most forces together without any consideration of direction.

Comment: ... which is not wrong during vector addition.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Here what you are facing problem is that the Fgx and Fn will not cancel out.I use the component method i.e. breaking fnet in x,y,z axis

The Fnet (in x direction) = Tx- Fgx -Ff(which i am assuming is frictional force)

The Fnet (in y direction) = Ty + Fn - Fgy

Here the normal force is not equal to Fgx as normal force is the force required to prevent penetrating of objects(though usually its value is Fgx).

If Ty is less than Fgy there will be a normal force acting to prevent penetration(whose value can change accordingly).
But is the Ty is greater than Fgy it will move up(if you pull a object with enough force it will move upwards). If equal it will just loose contact.